# jquery is not defined when i m using

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am getting error jquery is not defined.. please help me..

```
 jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#submitid').click(function(){
                if(jQuery('input[id="EnrollmentServiceAddress1"]').val() != ''){
                    var add2 = jQuery('input[id="EnrollmentServiceAddress2"]').val();
                    if(add2.indexOf('#', 0) && add2 != ''){
                        jQuery('input[id="EnrollmentServiceAddress2"]').val('#'+add2);
                    }
                }
                QadServer.current.submit("#EnrollmentServiceInformationForm");
            });

            jQuery('input[name="residence_type"]').click(function() {
                if(jQuery('input[name="residence_type"]:checked').val() == 'home') {
                    //            jQuery('#add_type').html('Home Number');
                    jQuery('#home_apt').slideUp('slow');
                } else if(jQuery('input[name="residence_type"]:checked').val() == 'apartment') {
                    jQuery('#add_type').html('Apartment Number');
                    jQuery('#home_apt').slideDown('slow');
                }
            });

            jQuery('.qad_suggestion').live('click',function() {
                qad_test();
            });

            jQuery('div[id="change_add"] > span').click(function() {
                jQuery('input[id="EnrollmentServiceAddress1"]').val('');
                jQuery('input[name="residence_type"]:checked').attr('checked', false);
                jQuery('#home_apt').hide();
                jQuery('#change_add').slideUp('slow', function() {
                    jQuery('#validate_add_block').slideDown('slow');
                });
            });

    <?php if($this->Session->check('Enrollment.social_security_number')) { ?>
                //        jQuery('#validate_add_block').hide(); //Old code
                //        jQuery('#change_add').show();
                jQuery('#validate_add_block').show(); //New code
                jQuery('#change_add').hide();
    <?php } ?>
                 init();
             });
```

Comment: have you add jquery reference url?
add this link to your head     <script src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: couple of things to check: 1. is your `<script src="jquery.js></script>` before those wall of script? 2. are you enclosing that script inside a `$(function() { })`?

Comment: @NiftyDude `$(function() { })` can't be a solution because for $ jQuery must already be loaded.

Comment: yes i added.. i checked in vie source also

Comment: Maybe you can show us more? Link to page, the include, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erro is because jquery file is not loading properly to avoid this  Try following code which include the jquery if its not included in your page ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined" || jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') 
{
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js")

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);
    } 
} 


    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('jQuery Library Loaded');
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 jQuery.noConflict()
```

else try to replace `$ with jQuery`.

Comment: If you think this answer is helpfyl for you please vote up it..thanks

Comment: actually this is not working for me... i said thanks for ur precious time ... and comment

Comment: ok thanksss..then if you use jquery , prototype js and more then one jquery version. then please check there sequence sometime it also give problem.. or please check in your jquery file which varriable it is using jQuery/$ or $j...

Answer (score 1):

Put this line at the top of your jquery code

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: Thats good but still something went wrong there. Cause if you have it included jQuery is defined. Check for 404, misspelling, lower case...

Answer (score 0):

try this in your view file
`<?php $this->Js->JqueryEngine->jQueryObject = 'jQuery'; ?>`